# Remove Cryptsetup LUKS encryption

Tags: linux, encryption, cryptsetup, whole-drive-encryption

I wanted to encrypt a flash drive but it didn't went well. Then I tried to remove the encryption but I am unable to do it.

Here is some info:
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           9f4cbeda-4733-4aa9-873f-764705300bee
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

```
Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 100669
        Salt:       59 c1 f4 ec 5a d2 17 ae 9f 2a 06 73 9c c2 b8 8e 
                    e8 02 0e 26 5c 8a 5a 33 a9 3e 98 ce 20 04 b8 c0 
        Digest:     f2 f9 3b 7e 53 48 2b 24 05 4d c3 b9 42 4c 3b 1e 
                    ef 8a 1f f5 22 85 25 de fc f9 e4 02 ac 0f 8b 9d
```

Comment: removing as in conversion while keeping any encrypted data on it, or as in reformatting from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "remove" LUKS encryption AFAIK, you need to format/recreate your partition.

Steps to convert it back to a normal USB drive:

```
sudo unmount /mount/point
sudo cryptsetup close /dev/mapper/name
cat /dev/zero > /dev/device1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/device1 (or mkfs.exfat/mkfs.vfat/mkfs.ntfs)
```

The `cat` command is not strictly necessary but really desired. If you don't run it you may discover files filled with random data.

`mkfs.ext4` may refuse to run saying that there's data on the partition, in which case use the `-F` flag.

Comment: Means I cant get back to normal file saving flash drive?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the insuctions how to make your flash drive unecrypted.

Comment: Yes Sir it worked, thanks a lot and Happy New Year.